# grep prints random character from bash script to the output file

Tags: bash, grep

I am not too used to bash script so kindly bear with me
The following code prints the array in the output file that grep creates. what is it that I am missing?

```
ids=(eebab078-6076-4ed7-91bb-624313865380)
ids+=(cd0b1f5d-2c86-43d4-ad86-b8beef7db4c9)

echo 'start processing'
for id in ${ids[@]}; do
    echo 'processing' $id
    grep -rih --exclude-dir={reprocessing} $id >> '../result-test.dat' 
done
echo 'end processing'
```

The output looks like this. I am only expecting the search results not the extra ids which is part of the array.

```
search results 
ids=(eebab078-6076-4ed7-91bb-624313865380)
ids+=(cd0b1f5d-2c86-43d4-ad86-b8beef7db4c9)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `-r` is non-standard, so I'll assume you're using gnu grep and that is a recursive option.  Your script seems to be in the directory tree that you are running in, so grep is reading your script and your script includes those lines that match.  `grep` is (correctly) printing the matching lines from your script.

Comment: If you omit `-h` and allow `grep` to print the filenames, perhaps that will be more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much @William Pursell

your answer helped me move in the right direction

used this script that worked

```
ids=(eebab078-6076-4ed7-91bb-624313865380)
ids+=(cd0b1f5d-2c86-43d4-ad86-b8beef7db4c9)
echo 'start processing'
for id in ${ids[@]}; do
    echo 'processing' $id
    grep -Rih --exclude-dir={reprocessing} --exclude=\*.sh $id >> '../result-test.dat' 
done
echo 'end processing'
```